# CentOS7 nginx permission denied for media and static

Tags: centos, permissions, nginx, django, uwsgi

### Hello

I have tried to deploy django web server for a week and finally I did it, but now I have a permission denied problem with nginx

#### /var/log/nginx/errors.log

```
/2016-07-12_1.png HTTP/1.0", host: "ip"      2017/08/28 08:22:38 [error] 873#0: *122 open() "/srv/www/Best/media/Profile Pictures/1/2016-07-12_1.png" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 94.183.22.168, server: ip, request: "GET /media/Profile%20Pictures/1/2016-07-12_1.png HTTP/1.0", host: "ip"
```

**www folder permission**

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root nginx 4096 Aug 27 15:05 www
```

**Best (project folder) permission**

```
drwxrw-r-- 9 uwsgi nginx 4096 Aug 27 21:27 Best
```

**media folder permission**

```
drw-rw-r-- 3 uwsgi nginx   4096 Aug 26 12:32 media
```

**static folder permission**

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 uwsgi nginx   4096 Aug 27 21:22 static
```

Comment: what about permissions of specific file `/srv/www/Best/media/Profile Pictures/1/2016-07-12_1.png`? Just to know, is SElinux enabled and enforced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `drwxrw-r--` for directories. It should be at least one of the following:

- `drwxrwxr-x` - Read, write and execute by the group, all can see contents too. Not recommended unless you really need write access by the group.
- `drwxr-xr-x` - Read and execute by the group, all can see contents too.
- `drwxr-x---` - Read and execute by the group.

You have not shown the permissions for the files either. This could also be an issue.

I have two options for you. Fix each folder and file individually or fix the lot in one go. Fixing the lot in one go may remove any special permissions (like write access) but that can be fixed later too if you know what you are doing.

Option 1, set per directory and file:

```
sudo chmod 750 /path/to/each/directory
sudo chmod 640 /path/to/each/file
```

Option 2, set for all:

```
sudo find /path/to/www/root -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 750
sudo find /path/to/www/root -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 640
```

Personally, I would use `750` (`drwxr-x---`) for directories and `640` (`-rw-r----`) for files on a website but you may want to use `755` (`drwxr-xr-x`) and `644` (`-rw-r--r--`).